# Does NSUserDefaults handle automatic termination safely?

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults

Apple's documentation says

> **NSUserDefaults temporarily disables sudden termination** to prevent process killing between the time at which a default has been set and the time at which the preferences file including that default has been written to disk.

Does it also do this for automatic termination, or must I `synchronize` manually when I suspect automatic termination may occur (e.g. when the application gets hidden)?

Comment: The edit was appreciated and improved the answer, but reviewers shot it down before I could approve it. Give it another shot?

Comment: @Catfish_Man I recreated Joe's edit into your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Shame Joe didn't get credit for it, but at least it's there now :)

Comment: @Catfish_Man That's OK; I up voted his question; more rep for that, anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to do anything specifically for automatic termination. The reason why is that automatic termination doesn't behave differently than ⌘Q (i.e. `-[NSApp terminate:]` is called if sudden termination is not enabled), and `NSUserDefaults` already handles ⌘Q just fine.

[Apple's 2011 WWDC presentation on automatic termination](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#resume-and-automatic-termination-in-lion) (registration required, starting around 34:00) has more information.

Comment: This is great if true, but I can't find any verification in the documentation - rather the opposite, I find e.g. the very scary "The system can *kill* the underlying process for an auto-terminable app *at any time*".

Comment: Sigh... I guess I need to go file a radar to get the documentation fixed. The WWDC talk entitled "Resume & Automatic Termination" has better information. You can also verify with the debugger yourself. Set a breakpoint on -[NSApplication terminate:], close all your windows, switch away, and induce memory pressure.

Comment: (I suspect whoever wrote that bit of the docs was both a bit overzealous, and confused about the difference between Sudden Termination and Automatic Termination)